# Entity Framework How To

Tags: entity-framework, entity

We have started the new project, n-tier with WPF. All classes are already defined and I'm responsible for the database part of the project. I have decided to use Entity Framework, and made the database and model, but am now kind of stuck - do not know how to proceed - connect the classes from the business logic with the Entity Framework. For example I'm supposed to populate the class that has properties from few tables in the database.

Any concrete help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read any of articles about entity framework?

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc3 or something else?

Comment: You should read [Programming Entity Framework - Julie Lerman](http://learnentityframework.com/)

Comment: This question is probably too broad to answer that. You should really start with some book or tutorial and ask a question about concrete problem.

Comment: For an intro see the EF tutorials at http://asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials -- there's one for Web Forms / EF Database First and one for MVC / EF Code First.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to use EF: Code first or database first.

If you want to keep what you have:

- Generate an EF model from your tables
- Then manually map the business objects to and from the EF objects

A better solution may be:

- Drop your database
- Use a code first approach to generate the database based on your business objects.

Checkout this video on EF http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=178